# Problem with IEnumerable in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, razor, t4mvc, mvccontrib-grid

I have a view that enumerates over a model.

Outside of the grid that enumerates over the model, I want to have a create link that accepts a parameter of `MeetingActionId`, that will bind the `ActionUpdate` object to a specific `MeetingAction`.

How do I get the create link to accept that property? at the moment i get the error

> ```
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain
>  a definition for 'MeetingActionId' and no extension method 'MeetingActionId' 
>  accepting a first argument of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found
> ```

I assume it's something to do with the `IEnumerable`. I was going to solve it by putting the grid in a partial, but that seems like a hacky solution to me.

Can anyone assist, and hopefully educate me as to why this is happening?

Thank you.

The code snippet below is using the MVCContrib Grid, and T4MVC for strongly typed action links.

```
@model IEnumerable<Actioner.Models.ActionUpdate>
@using MvcContrib.UI.Grid     

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListUpdates";
}

<h2>ListUpdates</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Add New Update",MVC.ActionUpdates.Create(Model.MeetingActionId))


@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column => {
   column.For(a=> a.UpdateText);
   column.For(a=> a.CreatedOn).Format("{0:d}");
   column.For(a=>a.CreatedBy);
})
```

EDIT: Thanks for the contributions guys. After some thinking i decided it would be better to have the grid of actionupdates rendered as a partial view within the 'details' view of the MeetingActions, thus avoiding this issue entirely.

This question could be closed

Comment: What are you trying to do? You have a view that's working with a collection of some model. You want to create a link inside this view. To which element of this collection you want to make this link point? If you can answer this question then you could take this particular instance of the model in the collection and use it in your T4 template.

Comment: Still confused! The link should create a new ActionUpdate. Every ActionUpdate belongs to a MeetingAction, so an ActionUpdate has a MeetingActionId, that i want to pass into the create Action in the ActionUpdate controller.

Answer (score 1):

Hi
I'm not sure that I understand this correctly but it seems like the Model is a list that contains items of type ActionUpdate, that type has a property called MeetingActionId. If that is the case the Model itself does not have the property MeetingActionId that you are trying to use. Perhaps you could to this:

`Model.First().MeetingActionId`

Comment: Well that works (certainly in terms of compiling at any rate :)), but i get the runtime error, 'Sequence contains no elements'.

Comment: Perhaps the list(model) is empty?

Comment: Wouldn't it be advisable to have a viewmodel that has two properties: MeetingActionId and IEnumerbale<ActionUpdate>? At least the nulls/empty values are not spoiling all the fun